# How can I know which control submitted a form in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have a form displaying a resource with several fields. The form is rendered inside the resources index page. On the form there are some radio buttons for selecting resource types. When a radio button is selected, I would like the form to be submitted and reloaded, as the form is displayed differently according to which resource type is selected. When the submit button is pressed, I would like the form to be replaced by something else.

I have a function that fires when the form is submitted, but I don't know how I can make it do one thing when the form is submitted by a radio button, and another thing when it is fired by the submit button.

How can I do this?

Comment: I suggest posting your second question separately and phrasing the first question (which doesn't seem to be ror-specific) in terms of client-side code.

Comment: Done! Since I have found out what was wrong according the second question (I tried to run server-side jquery on the client), I won't post this question separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question, why not store a special value in an <input type="hidden"> or a global variable in your 'select' handler right before you submit the form?

Then in your submit handler you could check to see if it's set -- this will tell you whether the submit was triggered from the radio button or in another way.